# How does Cake PHP know when a Controllers name is Plural or not

Tags: cakephp

I had a couple of cakePHP issues mostly because the names of my Controllers contained either non-plural or non nouns. Now my question is how does cakePHP know what the plural wording is for the controllers and if it's plural and if it's a noun, because I had issues when I named the controller hear_aboutus.php HearAboutUs class, and cake automatically knew the plural for medium and that is media, how does cakePHP find these?

Comment: Your controller filename should probably have been `hear_about_us_controller.php`. I believe when Cake's pluralization fails, it falls back to matching the name exactly (following its own conventions, of course).

Comment: @Justin - that I did try and did not work ;-)

Comment: When in debug mode, CakePHP will tell you what it's looking for when it can't find a controller. This has come in handy on many occasions, as usually you can figure out what you need to name your class (or file) from that.

Comment: a controller can always be single named. but then some automagic won't work. you will need to manually define the model in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inflector class handles that. Here's the source: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/cake/libs/inflector.php

Comment: fantastic, all makes sence now